# T4 From Partially Trusted ASP.NET shared webhost

Tags: asp.net, t4

Is there any way to host T4 in a partially trusted asp.net environment

Comment: Can you accomplish your task with a build-time template instead of a  runtime template?

Comment: Why do you need T4 ? Can't you use razor or [nhaml](http://code.google.com/p/nhaml/) for the generation ?

Comment: I want to source my templates from a database, and the generation won't be a development exercise ... it's targetted for end users to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your templates themselves don't change then you should use precompiled (runtime) templates which don't need a host - you just instantiate the template clases and call their TransformText() method.

Regular (design-time) T4 is not supported on the server.